# Design Pattern to write common method for all classes which extends Activity or Fragment

Tags: android, design-patterns, android-activity, android-fragments

> Implementation of task:-

*I need to implement a method lets say `commonMethod()`, which is going to be call on `onResume()` of an `Activity`, `MapActivity`, `Fragment` etc.. (In another work in all classes which having `onResume()`).*

And this can be done by easily to call commonMethod() at all places where I want.

> **But what I want is**

*I want to write a base class '`BaseActivity`' (for `Activity` family and another for `Fragment` family) which will extend `Activity` and write `commonMethod()` to `onResume()`. Now all `Activity` can extend the `BaseActivity` where I can call `super.onResume()`. I have no problem till now.*

Problem begins for

`com.google.android.maps.MapActivity` which extends `Activity` class. I have to write `commonMethod()` again for `MapActivity` (***which I don't want***).

So is there any way to do so? Is there any design pattern to do this?

Comment: :) Where do u have problem to understand? Its clear that I have no code for what I want.

Comment: The problem is `The MapActivity will inherit from the default class of android's Activity class`. Where I can't use my BaseActivity class and I have to write another base class for MapActivity...

Comment: Sir, we can not implements a class in java. that should be an interface

Comment: I do not understand your problem. Can you please rephrase it?

Comment: Have you solved this issue? What pattern did you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll *have* to call that method in direct sub-class of `MapActivity`. There's no way around that. Unless you are able to edit `MapActivity` itself.

If you are trying to avoid duplicate method body, place the said method in Application class, or some singleton, or just make the method static if possible.